# Cannot instantiate abstract class php

Tags: php, class, abstract

What is the problem this code?

```
abstract class Name{
    abstract function Show();
}
class SetValueName extends Name{
    public function Show(){
        return "Mani";
    }
}
$test = new Name();
```

**Error : Cannot instantiate abstract class**

Answer (score 1):

Like Error said, you can't instantiate an abractClass.

You should do 
`$test = new SetValueName()`